# issue in parsing json and displaying data 

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, json, ipad

i am using the below json  method and following code to parse json method and display the data which i need on a label.
i followed this link http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/tutorial-fetch-and-parse-json/ and many other but i am not getting the result what i need.Either it throws exception in below code line or else it displays null value.

```
NSDictionary* profile = [profileinfo objectAtIndex:0]; //throws exception
```

can anyone help me what is wrong in  the below code and what is missing so tat i get the values i.e, phonenumber,firstname and other data from json method.

```
//Json Method

{

"createdBy":"superadmin",
"createdOn":"2011-11-15T00:49:06+05:30",
"updatedBy":"superadmin",
"updatedOn":"2011-11-15T00:49:06+05:30",
"contactNumber":"9945614074",
"emailNotification":"true",
"firstName":"resident2",
"lastName":"user5",
"loginId":"jin",
"married":"false",
"message":"",
"preferredLanguage":"ko_KR",
"sex":"0",
"smsNotification":"false",
"status":"ACTIVE",
"subscribedPlans":"Intelligent Concierge",
"userName":"Cisco"

}

//code

- (void)loadData

{

 dataWebService = [[NSMutableData data] retain];


NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"URL LINK"]]retain];  

[[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

}


-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{


[connection release];    
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataWebService encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

self.dataWebService = nil;

NSArray* profileinfo = [(NSDictionary*) [responseString JSONValue] objectForKey:@"createdBy"]; 
[responseString release];    

NSDictionary* profile = [profileinfo objectAtIndex:0];

//fetch the data
NSNumber* numb = [profile objectForKey:@"contactNumber"];

NSString* name = [profile objectForKey:@"firstName"];

//set the text to the label
label.numberOfLines = 0;
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"contactNumber: %@ \n \n Name:  %@ \n \n",
             numb,name];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jsonValue is your dictionary.

replace

```
NSArray* profileinfo = [(NSDictionary*) [responseString JSONValue] objectForKey:@"createdBy"];
```

and

```
NSDictionary* profile = [profileinfo objectAtIndex:0];
```

with

```
NSDictionary * profile =  (NSDictionary*)[responseString JSONValue];
```

and now use objectForKey to get your values

Comment: ok so no need of using NSDictionary* profile = [profileinfo objectAtIndex:0]; this line code??

Comment: No just use NSDictionary * profile =  (NSDictionary*)[responseString JSONValue];

Comment: The {} of the json mean that the jsonvalue is an nsdictionary. Your code corresponds to {"createdBy":[{}]}